# Why can't Scala optimize this match to a switch?

Tags: scala, optimization, pattern-matching, switch-statement, constants

I have this [pattern match](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async/blob/master/postgresql-async/src/main/scala/com/github/mauricio/async/db/postgresql/codec/MessageEncoder.scala#L46-L63) that matches **only** on Byte values but when I add the `@switch` it says:

> could not emit switch to @switch annotated match

What am I missing here?

Just FYI, what I have tried already and did not work:

- Moving this constant to a Java interface and using `public static final byte` fields (I have also tried making them `int` instead of `byte`)
- Marking the fields as `final val` at the Scala `Message` companion object
- Marking the fields as `@inline` at the companion object

I'm definitely lost here.

Comment: It's [impossible](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.switch): `a non-literal may prevent switch generation: this would not compile`.

Comment: This post contains a dead link making the question incomplet, if original poster is still around, could you pleas fix that

Comment: now it includes the right link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer as provided at the [scala-user](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/v9kv3I-HR58/7GOHWXRXmToJ) forum was making the vals final and removing the `Byte` annotation:

```
object Message {
  final val Authentication = 'R'
  final val BackendKeyData = 'K'
  final val Bind = 'B'
  final val BindComplete = '2'
}
```

Now the `@switch` correctly generates a `lookupswitch` (it doesn't generate a `tableswitch` but it's good enough).